# Funnel analysis using MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, bigdata

I have a collection named 'event' it tracks event from mobile applications.
The structure of event document is

```
{
  eventName:"eventA",
  screenName:"HomeScreen",
  timeStamp: NumberLong("135698658"),
  tracInfo:
       {
         ...,
         "userId":"user1",
         "sessionId":"123cdasd2123",
         ...
       }
}
```

I want to create report to display a particular funnel:

eg:
funnel is : event1 -> event2 -> event3
I want to find count of:

1. event1
2. event1 then event2
3. event1 then event2 and then event3

and the session is also considered i.e occurred in single session.
Note: just want to be clear, I want to be able to create any funnel that I define, and be able to create a report for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is likely to revolve around an aggregation like this:

```
db.event.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: '$tracInfo.sessionId', events: { $push: '$eventName' } } }
])
```

where every resulting document will contain a sessionId and a list of eventNames.  Add other fields to the `$group` results as needed.  I imagine the logic for detecting your desired sequences in-pipeline would be pretty hairy, so you might consider saving the results to a different collection which you can inspect at your leisure.  2.6 features a new [`$out` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) for just such occasions.

Comment: Thank you for that hint to add group clause initially, i would add  _id :{sessionId + user} and the new $out operator will be of help as finding the sequence ll have to be done pragmatically i think

Comment: And if (e.g.) the time between events is of interest, of course you would want { $push: { 'name': '$eventName', 'time': '$timeStamp' } }

Comment: ya timeStamp is going in as it is involved in find average time between events as well as in checking the sequence of actions